# glm and Predict functions in R

Tags: r, function, probability, prediction

I am trying to implement the following lines in `R`

[image]

For that, I used the following functions, which I am not sure they are correct.

```
model.logit<-glm(formula = results ~ A + B, family = binomial(link = logit), data = dt)

predict.logit<-predict(object = model.logit, newdata = dt.NEW, type = "response")
```

I appriciate if you take a look.

Thanks

The sample data to test:

```
A<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
B<-c(5,4,7,3,9,2,3,1,9,2)
results<-c(1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1)
dt<-matrix(cbind(A,B,results),ncol=3)
colnames(dt) <- c("A","B","results")
dt<-data.frame(dt)
dt.NEW<-matrix(c(11,8,0),nrow=1)
colnames(dt.NEW) <- c("A","B","results")
dt.NEW<-data.frame(dt.NEW)
```

Comment: I was not sure the theta can be calculated by 'glm' function. That was my point

Comment: in case of using coef(model.logit), i will get three parameters (intercept, A,B) that in my case it need to be only one parameter. Am i right?

Comment: Alright. I am asking since theta here is used as only one parameter in the probability euqation (P), which it makes me confuse

Comment: "theta is a parameter vector. It is a single letter but refers to all regression coefficients". This sentece was really help ful. Thanks @李哲源ZheyuanLi

Comment: It is done ! tnx